# How to no-follow all external links automatically - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo, nofollow

I want to add `rel="nofollow"` attribute in all my external links. Below code works well on links comes with `http://` and `https://`. my problem is its not worked on links without `http` (ex: `/somepage.html`) how can i over come this.

Any solution highly appreciated.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esv85nx1/)**

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com">This is an internal link</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="http://google.com">And this is an external link, with no follow (working)</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="google.com">And this is an external link, with no follow (not-working)</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="https://plus.google.com/101147114025225446015/about">And this is an external link, with no follow (working)</a>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://www.somepage.com"])').attr('rel', 'nofollow');

jQuery('a[href*="https://"]:not([href*="http://www.somepage.com"])').attr('rel', 'nofollow');

jQuery('a[href*="https://"]:not([href*="https://www.somepage.com"])').attr("target", "_blank");
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esv85nx1/)**

Comment: why not verify link with current window.location. if same domain (disregard http/https) then ignore, else add rel=nofollow

Comment: `<a href="google.com">Link</a>` is not an external link. It effectively is a link to `<path-to-current-page-or-base>/google.com`.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding can you give me any examples?

Comment: @techfoobar you are right. can you see my fiddle i didn't get exact answers.

Comment: I just noticed what techfoodbar has responded. He has a point there. google.com will not take you to www.google.com. So what would be the expected outcome of the case:  href="google.com"  ?

Comment: @GoldPearl - Your current code is correct. You might want to add the case where you account for links starting in `//` as they can be external links (depending on the domain) - For example: `<a href="//google.com">Link</a>` is an external link.

Comment: Are you concern about losing Page Rank from your HTML page, caused links to external sites? If yes, I suggest you rewrite your HTML LINK code at server side, as any jQuery DOM validation done at the client won't count for any Search Engine crawler.